# Java prefix operator behavior

Tags: java

I was wondering why following code returns 0. I thought `num2` will be incremented before applied to `*=` and the second line would execute `num2 = 1*1`

```
int num2 = 0;
num2 *= ++num2;
System.out.println(num2);
```

Comment: It's `num2 = 0 * 1`...

Comment: No, `num2 *= ++num2` is equivalent to `num2 = num2 * ++num2` and as per the rules this evaluates to `num2 = 0 * 1`.

Comment: But, according to the precedence table [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) unary operators have higher precedence than assignment. So I thought value of 'num2' would be increased before `*=` is actually expanded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.2):

> A compound assignment expression of the form `E1 op= E2` is equivalent to `E1 = (T) ((E1) op (E2))`, where `T` is the type of `E1`, except that `E1` is evaluated only once.

So, your code is equivalent to:

```
num2 = (int) (num2 * ++num2);
```

The left-hand operand of the multiplication is zero, thus the result is zero.

Comment: But, according to the precedence table [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) unary operators have higher precedence than assignment. So I thought value of 'num2' would be increased before `*=` is actually expanded.

Comment: @Saiful don't confuse precedence with evaluation order. Java *always* evaluates left-to-right ([JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.7))